For people converting, what is the prohibition on working during yom kippur?
Shalom, I am converting. During Yom Kippur I was unsure as to how to interpret Vayikra 16:30 (specifically, that neither the citizen nor resident alien that resides among israel should work). I am aware that I am obligated to break at least one melacha during each shabbat, but I was unaware of if I should break one on Yom Kippur. One of my friends from shul who converted suggested that I break just in case for Shabbat (if you are reading this in the future, Yom Kippur 5785 fell on Shabbat.) In the end though, I carried without an eruv to break this. In my opinion this would've been fine since the shul I went to has no eruv at the moment, and I am thinking that me leaving the shul would also thus mean I am no longer residing amongst am yisrael so than I could do my melacha just in case after I had left. But I do wonder this for the future since there is little chance that my conversion will be finished by next Yom Kippur (and I figured that I should ask this for future people with the same question). But I am wondering if I did this correctly? I think I did what would be the best option halachicly but I am wanting other people's opinions on this, both for next year's Yom Kippur and for anyone who may have this question in the future. Thank you!

What did the rabbi supervising your conversion say?

I did not think to ask before and did not have time to speak to them during Yom Kippur.

The Rambam writes that a gentile may not treat any day of the week like Shabbat (Hilchot Melachim 10:9)

@Sholom Thank you! So I will take it that this means that no gentile should observe the prohibition on work fully on Yom Kippur (or on any yom tov, which I also ensure at least one melacha on already just in case).
Though torah says that no resident alien may work either as mentioned in the post, so I am going to think that this means, yes, people converting must break one melacha at least during Yom Kippur, but cannot do it whilst residing amongst am yisrael?

Interesting question. Thanks, and best wishes!

What the Torah means by “resides among Israel” means that he came to be of equal status as an Israelite i.e. fully converted
